# Group and subset time

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have time data in a data frame which looks like follows:

```
          date day       time      phone      lat      lon acc       update
6   12/08/2014 Tue 07:25:35PM 9052780809 17.41653 78.40537 3.9 1.406988e+12
44  12/08/2014 Tue 07:26:35PM 9052780809 17.41823 78.40344 3.9 1.406988e+12
114 12/08/2014 Tue 07:28:32PM 9052780809 17.41810 78.39846 3.9 1.406988e+12
152 12/08/2014 Tue 07:29:30PM 9052780809 17.41760 78.39512 3.9 1.406988e+12
188 12/08/2014 Tue 07:30:31PM 9052780809 17.41517 78.39426 3.9 1.406988e+12
223 12/08/2014 Tue 07:31:30PM 9052780809 17.41467 78.39434 3.9 1.406988e+12
```

Most of the times differ by 1-2 minutes but there are cases in between where they differ by more than 10 minutes like after the second reading. Consecutive readings may be on different days if there is a difference of more than 10 minutes between them. I want to insert a break after the reading which has more than 10 minute interval between them and insert them into another data frame to process them further.

```
             date day       time      phone      lat      lon acc       update
145315 16/08/2014 Sat 11:54:57AM 9052780809 17.41377 78.45923 3.9 1.406988e+12
145371 16/08/2014 Sat 11:55:56AM 9052780809 17.41626 78.45750 3.9 1.406988e+12
145426 16/08/2014 Sat 11:56:55AM 9052780809 17.41746 78.45547 4.0 1.406988e+12
162349 16/08/2014 Sat 05:02:51PM 9052780809 17.41562 78.44446 3.9 1.406988e+12
162404 16/08/2014 Sat 05:03:55PM 9052780809 17.41577 78.44113 3.9 1.406988e+12
162452 16/08/2014 Sat 05:04:51PM 9052780809 17.41638 78.43815 3.9 1.406988e+12
```

The original data has 8 columns and over 700000 rows.

Comment: Turn the data into POSIXct and then use difftime().

Comment: ... and then you could `split` whenever the difftime is > X minutes

Comment: Try `dt1 <- strptime(time1, format='%I:%M:%OS%p');split(time1, cumsum(c(FALSE,difftime(dt1[-length(dt1)], dt1[-1], unit='min')>10)))`

Comment: @SuryaPavanPynda Please check if the update helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pasting from the comments so that the question remains answered.  You can use `split` (suggested by @docendo discimus) and `difftime`(from @Laurik) to get the expected dataset.

Assuming that "time1" is the "time" column in your dataset ("dat"), convert "time1" to "POSIXlt" class using `strptime`, use `difftime` to get the difference in "minutes" between consecutive elements.  Here, I removed the last element and first element so that we can find the difference between current `dt1[-length(dt1)]` and next element `dt1[-1]`, apply the condition `>10`, `cumsum` the logical index and `split` the dataset based on that index to get a list of data.frames (`lst`).  It may be better to work within the list rather than creating individual data.frame objects.

```
dt1 <- strptime(dat$time1, format='%I:%M:%OS%p')
lst <- split(dat, cumsum(c(FALSE,difftime(dt1[-length(dt1)],
                            dt1[-1], unit='min')>10)))
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset `dat`

```
 dt1 <- with(dat, strptime(paste(date, time),
                     format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%OS%p'))

 indx <- cumsum(c(FALSE, abs(difftime(dt1[-length(dt1)], dt1[-1], 
       unit='min')) >10))
 split(dat, indx)
 #$`0`
 #        date day       time      phone      lat      lon acc       update
 #6   12/08/2014 Tue 07:25:35PM 9052780809 17.41653 78.40537 3.9 1.406988e+12
 #44  12/08/2014 Tue 07:26:35PM 9052780809 17.41823 78.40344 3.9 1.406988e+12
 #114 12/08/2014 Tue 07:28:32PM 9052780809 17.41810 78.39846 3.9 1.406988e+12
 #152 12/08/2014 Tue 07:29:30PM 9052780809 17.41760 78.39512 3.9 1.406988e+12
 #188 12/08/2014 Tue 07:30:31PM 9052780809 17.41517 78.39426 3.9 1.406988e+12
 #223 12/08/2014 Tue 07:31:30PM 9052780809 17.41467 78.39434 3.9 1.406988e+12

 #$`1`
 #           date day       time      phone      lat      lon acc       update
 #145315 16/08/2014 Sat 11:54:57AM 9052780809 17.41377 78.45923 3.9 1.406988e+12
 #145371 16/08/2014 Sat 11:55:56AM 9052780809 17.41626 78.45750 3.9 1.406988e+12
 #145426 16/08/2014 Sat 11:56:55AM 9052780809 17.41746 78.45547 4.0 1.406988e+12

#$`2`
#            date day       time      phone      lat      lon acc       update
#162349 16/08/2014 Sat 05:02:51PM 9052780809 17.41562 78.44446 3.9 1.406988e+12
#162404 16/08/2014 Sat 05:03:55PM 9052780809 17.41577 78.44113 3.9 1.406988e+12
#162452 16/08/2014 Sat 05:04:51PM 9052780809 17.41638 78.43815 3.9 1.406988e+12
```

#### data

```
dat <-     structure(list(date = c("12/08/2014", "12/08/2014", "12/08/2014", 
 "12/08/2014", "12/08/2014", "12/08/2014", "16/08/2014", "16/08/2014", 
 "16/08/2014", "16/08/2014", "16/08/2014", "16/08/2014"), day = c("Tue", 
 "Tue", "Tue", "Tue", "Tue", "Tue", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", "Sat", 
 "Sat", "Sat"), time = c("07:25:35PM", "07:26:35PM", "07:28:32PM", 
 "07:29:30PM", "07:30:31PM", "07:31:30PM", "11:54:57AM", "11:55:56AM", 
 "11:56:55AM", "05:02:51PM", "05:03:55PM", "05:04:51PM"), phone = c(9052780809, 
 9052780809, 9052780809, 9052780809, 9052780809, 9052780809, 9052780809, 
 9052780809, 9052780809, 9052780809, 9052780809, 9052780809), 
 lat = c(17.41653, 17.41823, 17.4181, 17.4176, 17.41517, 17.41467, 
 17.41377, 17.41626, 17.41746, 17.41562, 17.41577, 17.41638
 ), lon = c(78.40537, 78.40344, 78.39846, 78.39512, 78.39426, 
 78.39434, 78.45923, 78.4575, 78.45547, 78.44446, 78.44113, 
 78.43815), acc = c(3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9, 
 4, 3.9, 3.9, 3.9), update = c(1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 
 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 
 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12, 1.406988e+12
 )), .Names = c("date", "day", "time", "phone", "lat", "lon", 
 "acc", "update"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("6", "44", 
 "114", "152", "188", "223", "145315", "145371", "145426", "162349", 
 "162404", "162452"))
```

Comment: A bug in the code. It works only if the times are from different dates. If the times are from the same day it doesn't seem to split them.          [43] "10:19:13AM" "10:20:12AM" "10:21:11AM" "10:22:12AM" "10:23:15AM" "10:24:11AM" "10:25:12AM"
 [50] "10:26:12AM" "10:27:12AM" "10:28:12AM" "10:29:12AM" "10:30:11AM" "10:31:12AM" "10:32:11AM"
 [57] "10:33:12AM" "10:34:14AM" "02:32:27PM" "02:33:27PM" "02:34:27PM" "02:35:28PM" "02:37:27PM"
 [64] "02:38:28PM" "02:39:28PM" "02:40:28PM" "02:41:27PM" "02:42:28PM" "02:43:27PM" "02:44:27PM"
 [71] "02:45:27PM" "02:47:30PM" "02:48:28PM" "02:49:27PM"

Comment: @SuryaPavanPynda Please update your post with a new example and expected output.  Do you have a date column?  In that case, please do show it in your post rather than in the comments (as it is difficult to get the format correctly).  Also, use dput to show a subset of data. ie. `dput(head(data))`

Comment: made the changes. Please have a look now. Thanks